# Read .mpp file from Python

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

Need some help to make my python script to read a .mpp file. I got to this point with the code but I am not able to open the file. I have tried to change the source path in many different way but I keep getting the same error:

File "C:\Users\gsobral\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\A7107640-94DF-1068-855E-00DD01075445x0x4x8.py", line 19772, in FileOpen
return self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(102, LCID, 1, (11, 0), ((12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (3, 48), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16), (12, 16)),Name
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (1004, '', 'Project cannot open the file.', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\VBAPJ.CHM\x00', 131072, 0), None)

```
import win32com.client
import datetime as dt

MSP= "Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library"
where = "./MSPRJ.py"

from win32com.client import makepy
import sys
sys.argv=['',"-o",where, MSP]
makepy.main()

import MSPRJ
g = globals()
for c in dir(MSPRJ.constants):
    g[c] = getattr(MSPRJ.constants,c)

msp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("MSProject.Application")

msp.FileOpen(r"C:\\test.mpp")
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone give some help with this?

Comment: This may not solve everything, but note that you are using an r-string so backslashes don't need to be escaped: `r"C:\\test.mpp"` is equivalent to `"C:\\\\test.mpp"`

Comment: Perhaps its a permissions issue? Try moving `test.mpp` to the same directory as the script.

Comment: Oli, thank you for the comment. Both script and file are in the same dir. In this case in my desktop.
I have also tried to use msp.FileOpen(r"test.mpp") but I am getting the same error.

Comment: It could be a corrupt file like in this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_project-mso_other-mso_2016/ms-project-cant-open-file/d3466fc8-f4d3-44f4-be5e-3b5e6ea08037

Comment: The file looks ok. I can open it with MS Project. I have have created a new project just in case that one was corrupted but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Did further investigation and apparently the module win32com.gen_py can cause this error when it has no attribute. I found a script that can clean the cache and try to activate the module again. Tried the solution but it doesn't look like I am actually activating the project plan and reading the data. Keeping getting attribute missing error.